# Modificiar url con jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tengo la siguiente url

**https://localhost/test.html?referrerPageUrl=&query=**

Quiero que al hacer click en un botón de mi sitio web la url que aparece en el navegador quede de la siguiente manera sin recargar la página

**https://localhost/test.html?referrerPageUrl=PRUEBA&query=**

Actualmente he probado lo siguiente pero no me funciona

```
        var post_slug = 'referrerPageUrl=PRUEBA';
        history.replaceState(null, null, post_slug);
```

Comment: Revisa [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19279428/5587982). Ten en cuenta que la API History es relativamente nueva, por lo que no funcionará en ciertas versiones de navegadores. [Puedes consultar la compatibilidad en `caniuse.com`](https://caniuse.com/history).

Comment: Conoces alguna otra formar de hacer lo que busco que tenga mejor compatibilidad?

Comment: ¿Se podría saber por qué quieres hacer eso?

Comment: Es una aplicación externa que necesita saber en sitio web está a través de la URL, en ese parámetro está el nombre del sitio web donde se encuentra

Comment: Ya, pero aquí se trata de **modificar** la URL. ¿Qué es lo que justifica tener que **modificarla**?

Comment: Que el servicio externo coja ese parámetro y sepa en que site se encuentra

Comment: No entiendo realmente qué significa *que el servicio externo coja ese parámetro y sepa en que site se encuentra*. Intuyo que hay un error de planteamiento en lo que intentas hacer y ahí reside el problema, precisamente por eso te pregunté qué justificaba tener que hacer esto. Por ahora no veo nada que lo justifique, y algo tan importante como el contexto no queda reflejado en tu pregunta. El enlace que te puse más arriba hace lo que quieres hacer, pero quizá ni siquiera haya que hacer esto, sino resolver el problema de otro modo.